# how to listen the special class initialization?

Tags: java, interface, annotations, initialization

Here I want to listen some special classes initialization; when those classess initialization
 I will do some actions.

Present I want to use interface or annotation, but how to implement this?

Comment: Are you trying to create classes which implement interfaces?

Comment: Please provide an example showing what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have solved this problem，we use the javassist;the code likes:

```
Configuration conf = (Configuration) entry.getValue();
        String clazz = conf.getClazz();
           try {
        CtClass ctClass = ClassPool.getDefault().get(clazz);
        String appendCode = "{com.broada.bsp.gene.config.management.ConfigurationManager.manager.inject(this);\n}";
        CtConstructor constructor[] = ctClass.getDeclaredConstructors();

        for (CtConstructor ctConstructor : constructor) {
            ctConstructor.insertAfter(appendCode);
        }

            ctClass.toClass();
```

thank you for your answers,  Himanshu Bhardwaj !

here we can not use you solutions,because we can not change the users new java  object actions, use javassist, we just append come code after the constructors, so the users java new the objects,needn't change their behaves.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **observer design pattern** here. Have a listener class (let it be singleton) expose some method, which will be invoked in the constructor. So as soon as the object gets initialized the function gets called in the singleton letting you do the required actions.

UPDATE:

Approach # 1

```
 public class CreateListener {
    public static void class1ObjectCreated () {
        //Do some actions here
    }
 }


public class Class1 {
   public Class1 () {
       //Do something
       CreateListener.class1ObjectCreated();
   }

   public Class1 (...args) {
       //Do something
       CreateListener.class1ObjectCreated();
   }
}
```

Approach # 2:

```
 AspectJ ruled out.
```

Approach # 3:

```
@PostConstruct depends on if application is Java-EE-6 compliant.
```

Comment: Suppose I have a class A; it implemented Configurable interface or annotated with ConfigurableAnn; The user can use class A,just new it; when it inited，some actions will invoked. Or I can express in it this way: It has a AOP point at the end of the class A constructor. We can use the spring BeanPostProcessor to handle this. But It can not use new,It must get the Object from the spring bean container.So we just quit the spring.

Comment: As I konw the aspectJ can also handle this,Maybe code is like this :            pointcut pTest2():execution(com.*.*.*.new());        after():pTest2(){  
 System.out.println(thisJoinPoint.getSignature().toString());
};                                                                              But My boss just says forget aspectJ,do not use it in our project.  SO I dont kown how to do this? can anyone help??